# easiest way to output HTML file as PDF using VB.NET

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, pdf, file-conversion

I have generated an HTML file in my application.  Now I want to output that as a PDF file. How to do that easily with VB.NET? The process must be offline and I can't use any paid library or API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have write easiest way to write html to pdf code using NRerco Pdf library which available free, Install nuget package

PM > Install-Package NReco.PdfGenerator

```
      Create HtmltoPdf()
       {
       if (System.IO.File.Exists("HTMLFile.html"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("HTMLFile.html");
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("HTMLFile.html", html);
        var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("export.pdf"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("export.pdf");
        }

        htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("HTMLFile.html", null, "export.pdf");
   }
```

Comment: You just forgot to mention that it is not free to use, it is only free to download, which makes little sense. Your code generates an error saying "..you need some licence..". Currently it is for 199 USD.